# How to concatenate a string name to a ListName

Tags: c#

I have a class with some listNames.
I want to dynamically concatenate a string to the ListName like `List1, List2`, as I already have `List1,  List2` declared in another class:

```
for (i=1; i <= staffsT; i++)
{
    if (dgOut.Data.InstDigitalDetails.digitStaffDetails.Count > (staffRows)*i)
    {
        List<DigitStaffDetails> stafDt = new List<DigitStaffDetails>();
        stafDt = (from r in dgOut.Data.InstDigitalDetails.digitStaffDetails  select r).Take(staffRows*i).ToList(); 


         string listName = "dgOut.Data.InstDigitalDetails.digitStaffDetails" + i.ToString();

         //here want to type cast string name to objectName 
         listName= staffDt;                        
      }
 }
```

Any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you give us some pseudo-code to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: I have a class with following lists- List1<object>,List2<object>. i have to get this in a for loop like this- List+i.ToString - and assign the value of object. Did u get my question now

Comment: Could you update your question please?

Comment: Please show some code of what you've already written. As it is, it's not entirely clear (at least to me), what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I think you can make use of linq to generate list names easily

```
    IEnumerable<int> range = Enumerable.Range(1, staffsT);
    IEnumerable<string> listNames = range.Select(i => "dgOut.Data.InstDigitalDetails.digitStaffDetails" + i);
```

resulting enumeration will be the concatenate list names.

> dgOut.Data.InstDigitalDetails.digitStaffDetails1
>
> dgOut.Data.InstDigitalDetails.digitStaffDetails2
>
> ....
>
> dgOut.Data.InstDigitalDetails.digitStaffDetailsN

This is just a example implementation, you may adjust it according your usage.

Comment: Your listName will be of type string not type of List<object>. how i can assign list object to string

Comment: You may simply choose `IEnumerable<object> listNames` to get a list of objects. but I would appreciate if you could elaborate your concern a bit more, perhaps with some example what you are trying to achieve.